# OpenCV - Detecting Body Parts with Fixed Camera, Known Background, and Only 1 Human

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-recognition

I'd like to do identification and localization of body parts on some videos that I have. In this particular case, I know the following:

- The camera is totally fixed, so the background can be subtracted to identify the changes between frames.
- The background is known. I have a blank, starting image of the background without a human to use as a reference.
- There is only 1 human in the ROI.

The human can take a lot of different positions-- effectively they're playing a game of twister with the background. They may not have their entire bodies in the shot. I'm interested in basically drawing up to 10 different rotated rectangles around the different points of free motion. I'm thinking it might be possible by doing an iterative minRectArea with an increasing number of rectangles, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is an example of what poses might look like, with a blank background for reference and an outline of what I'm trying to come up with:

[image: Blank background image]

[image: An example pose]

[image: A hand labeled version of the pose]

Comment: A really good start would be to focus your lens.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter, right? Most algorithms do some sort of smoothing on the images anyway and as long as the lens is consistently blurry, the principles of the algorithm should hold.

Comment: show us your code..